# how to display a number/word at a percentage chance?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to figure out how to do this thing on my own for a while now. I need to create something that will allow the user, by pushing a button on screen or refreshing the browser window, to generate numbers/words. The thing is I have figured out how to do this so that the numbers/words are generated randomly, but what I need is to ensure they generate at a percentage chance so that one will have a 95% chance of returning to screen and another a 20% chance and so on.

I know this is more of a favor for service than a question, but I have been trying to figure this out on my own for too long. I totally understand if I get kicked from site/no one gives me the time of day.

Below is the code I use to generate random numbers but as explained above I want to change this so each number is generated at percentage chance.

```
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
<p id="demo4"></p>
<p id="demo5"></p>
<p id="demo6"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML =
Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML =
Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML =
Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML =
Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
document.getElementById("demo5").innerHTML =
Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
document.getElementById("demo6").innerHTML =
Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

PS : I have no programming experience FYI.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: *"one will have a 95% chance of returning to screen and another a 20% chance and so on"* - Shouldn't the chances add up to 100%? Or are you saying that a single click of the button could show any number of words simultaneously, with each word having its own percentage chance of appearing? What do you mean by "generate words"? Select from a predetermined list of words, or randomly put letters together?

Comment: @nnnnnn "Or are you saying that a single click of the button could show any number of words simultaneously, with each word having its own percentage chance of appearing?"  <---- Exactly this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was clarified in a comment that a single click of a button (or page refresh, whatever) could show any number of words simultaneously, with each word having its own percentage chance of appearing.

On that basis, you need to define a list of words with their chances, so maybe an array of objects like:

```
var words = [ { word: "Hello", chance: 10 }, { word: "Hi", chance: 95 }, /* etc. */ ]
```

Or just an object where each property name is a word with the associated value giving the chance of appearance:

```
var words = { "Hello": 10, "Hi" : 95, /* etc. */ }
```

Either way, when the button is clicked you iterate over the list, and decide for each one whether to display it. For this demo I've gone with the second option of using an object rather than an array of objects:

```js
var words = {
  "Green": 95, "Yellow": 25, "Blue": 50, "Orange": 75, "Black": 33, "Purple": 10
}

document.getElementById("generate")                // when the button
  .addEventListener("click", function() {          // is clicked

    var output = []                                // create an empty array, then
    Object.keys(words).forEach(function(word) {    // for each word in the list
      if (Math.random() * 100 < words[word])       // decide whether to display
          output.push(word)                        // if so add to output array
    })

    // finally, turn output array into a string separated by <br> elements
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output.join("<br>")
})
```

```html
<button id="generate">Show words</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

You could change the last line to `output.join(", ")` to show the selected words as a comma-separated list. Or you could add very slightly more complicated code to output each word in its own li element in a ul, or whatever.

Comment: This is an incredibly thorough answer and the 'Run code snippet' proves it is exactly what I need.  I am still struggling to recreate this from scratch, but I will continue until I figure it out.  I think my issue is organizing it in the appropriate sections of the entire body of the program.  Thank you @nnnnnn for the precise and accurate response.

Answer (score 0):

If you can generate random numbers, you can use the generated number with  a series of if statements to choose which word to display. So if you wanted your word to be 'apple' 25% of the time and 'banana' 75%:

```
function randomWord(){
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  var word;

  if (num < 26){
      word = 'apple';
  } else {
      word = 'banana';
  }

  return word;
}
```

Etc for however many options you want to consider.

**Edit:** after re-reading and seeing your code, this doesn't exactly answer your question, but it might help you anyway.

Comment: Thank you Raymond.  This bit of code seems like it is a good place for me to start.  I will start playing with it tonight.  My first post and I am already loving this community.  Hope I can be of help at some point.